# Horizontal scroll in Excel with keyboard

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2016

Is there a keyboard shortcut in excel for horizontal scrolling. I'm aware of `alt+pgdn` and `alt+pgup`, but it's scrolling for whole view area. Is there  any keyboard shortcut for scrolling one column at a time. Like you would scroll when you click on arrows on horizontal bar or when you are scrolling vertically with mouse wheel (single row).

Thanks xD.

Comment: try shift/scrollwheel [I've never tested it on Win but that's standard behaviour for Mac]

Comment: Excel will scroll one column left or right if your cursor is in the column on the respective edge of the screen and you attempt to move it with the arrow keys in that direction - that is, if columns F through M are shown on the screen, with the cursor in column F, pressing the left arrow will scroll one column so that you see E through L; if the cursor is in column M, pressing the right arrow will scroll one column so that you see G through N.

Comment: If you hit the Scroll Lock key then the arrow keys will allow you to scroll in all directions

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad is there any way to do it without scroll lock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/move-or-scroll-through-a-worksheet-06fc34b8-64bb-4d78-9b62-34656d700f82), it's *scroll lock*+arrows.

Comment: What if there is no scroll Lock on newer versions of laptops?

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + Scroll Mouse Wheel